# How to make a button go back to previous window on pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, designer

I want to go back to previous window that I have been clicked

I make two window. First is Main_Menu.py and second is Current_Stalls.py I want to make a transition from Main_Menu to Current_Stalls by clicking button Current Stalls. Then after go to Current Stalls window I made button name Back To Home in order to go back to Main Menu page. However after I written up the code it fail to import the other module

## The Main Menu Program

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Current_Stalls import Ui_OtherWindow2
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def openWindow2(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_AnotherWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        MainWindow.hide()
        self.window.show()

        self.current_stall = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.current_stall.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 200, 231, 41))
        self.current_stall.setObjectName("current_stall")
        self.current_stall.clicked.connect(self.openWindow2)
```

## The Current Stall Program

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Main_Menu import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_AnotherWindow(object):
    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QAnotherWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        AnotherWindow.hide()
        self.window.show()   

        self.backHome = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backHome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 20, 161, 41))
        self.backHome.setObjectName("backHome")
        self.backHome.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
```

Comment: in what way does it fail? It looks like both scripts import the other which doesn't make much sense

Comment: This could really use a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and as @SimonN has stated sort-of your Class UI_AnohterWindow should not be importing UI_MainWindow

Comment: How to make the program ? Could you give the code ? @DennisJensen

Comment: No I cannot make your MRE because I do not know what your program actually looks like that you use to run the above 2 classes -- it is why you need to create that MRE and you need to make it such that it mimics what it is you are doing where you are experiencing the issue -- so that when we copy/paste it we experience the same issue.  As it stands if I copy/paste what you posted I cannot run it because it is not a runable bit of code